# How can i change line between merge scopes?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

```
$scope.message = $scope.share.Name_en.concat($scope.share.Address_en);
$scope.shareviasms = function() {

$cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaSMS($scope.message, null) 
}
```

The function work perfect and show the $scope.message which is merge with 2 scopes but i would like to change line or leave space between the $scope.share.Name_en and $scope.share.Address_en

Comment: concat manually ? like "your space character" + ? ^^ -> $scope.message = $scope.share.Name_en + ' ' + $scope.share.Address_en;

Comment: thanks for you answer.This work only when i want to leave space.

Comment: well, leave whatever string you want like this $scope.message = $scope.share.Name_en+whateverStringVariable+$scope.share.Address_en ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.join` :

```
$scope.message = [$scope.share.Name_en, $scope.share.Address_en].join(" ");
```

Or simply (as said by comments)

```
$scope.message = $scope.share.Name_en + ' ' + $scope.share.Address_en;
```